# How much time it will take Verification process completed || google oauth2 || youtube partner scopes

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

Use of this API scope will be restricted until it is approved

our consent screen is being verified. This may take up to several days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use.
Before your users authenticate, this consent screen will allow them to choose whether they want to grant access to their private data, as well as give them a link to your terms of service and privacy policy. This page configures the consent screen for all applications in this project.

Verification status
Being verified (Last approved consent screen is still in use)

Because you've added a sensitive scope, your consent screen requires verification by Google before it's published.

Answer (score 3):

How long verification takes depends greatly upon the application, and the scopes it uses.  I have seen anything from a few days to six weeks+ and Google asking for a video of your application running.

This is why its good to start the process while you are still in development developers with access to the project in google developer console should still be able to use your application while you are in the verification process.

Comment: I just went through the process. I had to edit my application 3 times, but every time they replayed within a day, it took 5 days in total